# Teradata Linked Server in SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, teradata, linked-server

I am trying to connect to Teradata using a Linked Server in SQL Server 2005. When I try to use SQL Server to connect using OPENQUERY, I get the following errors:

Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "TDOLEDB.1" for linked server "TERADATA" reported an error. Access denied.

Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "TDOLEDB.1" for linked server "TERADATA".

When I "Test Connection" the test succeeds, but when I try to view the Catalog default Tables in SQL Server Management Studio, I get the same error. I have Visual Studio installed on the computer running SQL server (it is a dev box), and I can connect using the OLE DB driver and I can run my query, and navigate to the Catalogs default Tables. Is there some trick to getting a linked server to work with Teradata? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

--CDW

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully these will help:

[TeraData Forums](http://www.teradataforum.com/)

[TERADATA ADVISORY GROUP SETS BEST PRACTICES FOR BUSINESS OBJECTS AND TERADATA CUSTOMERS](http://www.businessobjects.com/pdf/partners/teradata_advisory_group.pdf)

[Best Practices for Teradata Deployments](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12104_01/books/AnyInstAdm/AnyInstAdmPreInstall12.html)

[Teradata Developer Exchange](http://developer.teradata.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Can you select from the DBC.Tables views with the user you are connecting as?

```
SELECT * from DBC.TablesVX
```

Answer (score 1):

you might try...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/cbefb8c9-57e5-48d6-9c47-dc797bbf444b

where Brian says "Setting the TODLEDB.1 provider properties in SQL Server Management Studio to “allow inprocess” worked in overcoming this type of issue."

regards

zdba